# Saving a TXT file (tab separated) via VBA with different results

Tags: excel, vba

When saving an Excel worksheet using the standard save command in the "Text (tab separated)" format, cells with numerical values are saved in the text file, separated by commas.

If I save the file with the following VBA line, it works fine with my own files and the addition 'Local: = True'!

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: = cPfad_Ziel & cDateiName_Ziel, _
     FileFormat: = xlText, CreateBackup: = False, Local: = True
```

Unfortunately this does not work with a foreign Excel file!

The text file is also saved here, but with dots as decimal separators!

I have already worked through all the settings and options I know in Excel ...

Could it be that not only the settings of the local computer and the locally installed Excel instance are relevant, but that there is also a file-specific property that only leads to this behavior with this one file?

I am grateful for any relevant advice!

---

Beim Speichern eines Excel-Arbeitsblattes über den Standard-Speicherbefehl im Format "Text (Tabstopp getrennt)" werden Zellen mit Zahlenwerten mit Komma getrennt in die Textdatei gespeichert.

Wenn ich die Datei mit folgender VBA-Zeile speichere, funktioniert das mit meinen eigenen Dateien und dem Zusatz 'Local:=True' ebenfalls einwandfrei!

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=cPfad_Ziel & cDateiName_Ziel, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```

Leider klappt das bei einer fremden Excel-Datei nicht!

Zwar wird auch hier die Textdatei gespeichert, allerdings mit Punkten als Dezimaltrenner!

Alle mir bekannten Einstellungen und Optionen in Excel hab ich schon durch...

Kann es sein, dass hier nicht nur die Einstellungen des lokalen Rechners und der lokal installierten Excel-Instanz relevant sind, sondern es noch eine dateispezifische Eigenschaft gibt, die nur bei dieser einen Datei zu diesem Verhalten führt?

Bin für jeden sachdienlichen Hinweis dankbar!

Comment: If the OP does not understand English, what good is the translation? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302318/language-corrections/302319#302319

Comment: and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts

Comment: and from the FAQ: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680

Comment: Welp... shows you I still don't fully know the rules of this site!